# AngularJS: How to initialize a $scope attribute

Tags: angularjs

I wrote the following small angular code snippet:

**html file:**

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      ....
    </div>
</body>
```

**javascript file:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.white_sld = get_init_white_sld();
  $scope.get_soldier_style = function is_soldier(loc) {

  var sld_color = get_soldier_color(loc);
  if (sld_color == "") {
      return ""; // no soldier in this square
  } else {
      return {
          'width': '80%', 'height': '80%', 'border-radius': '80%', 'background-color': sld_color,
          'margin': 'auto auto', 'vertical-align': 'middle'
      }
  }

  function get_soldier_color(loc) {
      for (var i = 0; i < white_sld.length; i++) {
          if ((loc[0] == white_sld[i][0]) && (loc[1] == white_sld[i][1])) {
              return "white"
          }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < black_sld.length; i++) {
          if ((loc[0] == black_sld[i][0]) && (loc[1] == black_sld[i][1])) {
              return "black"
          }
      }
      return ""; // no soldier found
  }
 }
});

function get_init_sld_line(x_loc, y_loc, color) {
    var line_sld = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        line_sld.push(new Soldier(x_loc + 2 * i, y_loc, color));
    }
    return line_sld;
}


function get_init_white_sld() {
    var init_white_sld = [];
    init_white_sld.push(get_init_sld_line(0, 0, "white"));
    init_white_sld.push(get_init_sld_line(1, 1, "white"));
    init_white_sld.push(get_init_sld_line(0, 2, "white"));
    return init_white_sld;
};
```

My problem with this code is that after the line "$scope.white_sld = get_init_white_sld();", $scope.white_sld gets the return value of the function get_init_white_sld(). However, when it gets inside the function 'is_soldier', then $scope.white_sld becomes undefined. My question is why and how can I resolve it?

Comment: What is ```get_init_white_sld```?

Comment: I added it to the code snippet

Comment: `get_init_sld_line` does nothing. You declare an array, push to it, then do nothing with that array. You forgetting a `return`/

Comment: And no, white-sld is not null: https://plnkr.co/edit/vW5c0e4ZDv9hsma4OIoZ

Comment: @tymeJV, I added 'return' to 'get_init_sld_line' and still I see no change.

Comment: @CrazySynthax how do you tell that $scope.white_sld is null. You're not displaying it anywhere in the posted code. Why don't you post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem in a plunkr, just like I did (without being able to reproduce it)?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bLnimwywuDUpe0pValuv?p=preview

Comment: I just put a breakpoint in line number 17 in app.js, and saw that it's undefined.

Comment: That's probably because you chose to name the first argument of `is_soldier()` $scope, thus hiding the actual controller $scope variable inside that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you should use `$scope.white_sld` within that function, not just `white_sld`.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the plunkr please check

Actually you forgot to add return statement in get_init_sld_line function.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kYebs1pFznaDpHlFDodK?p=preview

```
return line_sld;
```